# Which one is the correct one? every lesson or every lessons?

Tags: grammatical-number

"I attend every lesson" or "I attend every lessons". Which one is correct?

Comment: Hi Xavier, welcome to ELU!  I'm afraid this question is a little basic for this site; are you aware of our sister site, [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com)?  You might benefit from asking this over there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I attend every lesson

or

> I attend all lessons

Answer (score 1):

When you say *every*, it refers to a single lesson. (Singular)

So,

> I attend every lesson.

is correct.

When you say collectively, then you need to use plural *lessons*.

> I attend all lessons.